# Django database learn itself

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a system that relies on other models but want to make it a little more open-ended as my users demand a bit more sometimes.

currently for arguments sake I have `2 authors` in an `Author` model.

```
john, james
```

When a user adds a book, and the `Author` is not available, how do I add a `other` field in the form, that if selected, then generates an extra field where the user can enter the name of the `Author` and the form handling is in such a way that the new Author gets added and selected on submission?

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def new(request, template_name='authors/new.html'):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AuthorForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        newform = form.save(commit=False)
        newform.user = request.user
        newform.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

else:
    form = AuthorForm()

context = { 'form':form, }

return render_to_response(template_name, context,
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your book model is this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    #etc.
```

try something like this:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    other = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        other = self.cleaned_data.get('other')
        author = self.cleaned_data.get('author')
        if author is None or author == '': 
            self.cleaned_data['author'] = Author(name=other).save()

        return self.cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

If author would be a manytomanyfield:

class BookForm(ModelForm):
    other = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    other = self.cleaned_data.get('other')
    author = self.cleaned_data.get('author')
    if other is not None or other != '':
        for newauthor in other.split(','): #separate new authors by comma. 
            self.cleaned_data['author'].append(Author(name=newauthor).save())

    return self.cleaned_data

class Meta:
    model = Book
```